# Using AWS v4 Signatures on RestSharp requests?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, restsharp

I am using RestSharp (via openapi-generator) for an API which is on AWS API Gateway and uses AWS IAM authentication. This requires me to create a signature of the request and include it as a header. The input to this signature is defined as:

```
CanonicalRequest =
  HTTPRequestMethod + '\n' +
  CanonicalURI + '\n' +
  CanonicalQueryString + '\n' +
  CanonicalHeaders + '\n' +
  SignedHeaders + '\n' +
  HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload))
```

My issue is that it seems the IAuthenticator interface does not give access to the headers and I'm not even sure it is 'late enough' in the process to give the desired results.

The process is described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

There is an existing library (Aws4RequestSigner @ https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aws4RequestSigner/) which do this for you, but they are based on the HttpRequestMessage.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to implement AWS Requests with Signature v4 via RestSharp?